# Using Python with pygerrit2 Library to make API call to Gerrit From Power BI Desktop

Tags: python-3.x, rest, powerbi, gerrit

I've recently started using power BI. I am trying to get data from Gerrit Rest Api Using Python. The following code works fine when I run it locally on my machine.

```
    from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
    from pygerrit2.rest import GerritRestAPI
    auth = HTTPDigestAuth('####', '##############')
    rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://gerrit.****.com', auth=auth)
    changes = rest.get("/projects/?d")
```

In Power BI it doesn't cause any errors, but there are no results in the resulting Navigator Pane.

This seems to be the same problem outlined in this forum https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Load-JSON-as-source-via-Python/td-p/485375

But I don't see any real resolution.

Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change from:

```
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://gerrit.****.com', auth=auth)
```

To:

```
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://gerrit.****.com/a', auth=auth)
```

Without the "/a" the authentication doesn't work and you're getting an empty project list.

See more details about the authentication in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication).

Comment: Doesn't work. The /a/ is put in by the pygerrit2 library. As I mentioned the python script works fine outside Power Bi. I get the project list.